# How can I move calculations in View to Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I´m very new to ROR and I have stumbled up on a problem. I believe it´s a newbie problem, but I´m  not sure if it´s. I´m building this app were users should be able to enter the amount of paper use in their business and from there the app calculates their eco footprint so to say.

at login the user enters their staff number. The staff number is used to divide with paper_weight etc. ( see in view example).

I know it basically works the way it is now, but I´m aware of this is not the best practice.

I also wanted to move the div containing the running totals to application.html.erb but I can´t do that since my calculations are in the View but not in the Model.

here is a link to the github repo https://github.com/DadiHall/SprettaEMS1.5

Are there any other ways to do this? Can someone please advise me?

my index.html.erb view

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10  ">

    <h1>Pappírsnotkun</h1>
    <table class=" well table table-hover">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Dags</th>
                <th>Tegund</th>
                <th>Þyngd</th>
                <th>Kostnaður</th>
                <th>Þar af umhvm. pappír</th>
                <th>Pappírs magn m.v. Stöðugildi</th>
                <th>Hl.f. Umhvm. Pappírs</th>
                <th>Fjöldi trjáa m.v. magn pappírs</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

            <tbody>     
                    <% paper_total_cost = 0 %>
                    <% paper_total_trees = 0 %>
                    <% paper_total_staff_ratio = 0 %>   
                <% @papers.each do |paper| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= paper.date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") %></td>
                        <td><%= paper.paper_type %></td>
                        <td><%= paper.paper_weight %> -kg.</td>
                        <td><%= paper.paper_cost %> -kr.</td>
                        <td><%= paper.env_paper_weight %> -kg.</td>
                        <td><%= (paper.paper_weight.to_i / current_user.staff) %> kg/stöðugildi </td>
                        <td><%= (( paper.env_paper_weight / paper.paper_weight)* 100) %>%</td>  
                        <td><%= (( paper.paper_weight.to_f/1000)*15) %></td>

                        <td><%= link_to 'Sýna', paper, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-info' %></td>
                        <td><%= link_to 'Uppfæra', edit_paper_path(paper), class: 'btn btn-xs btn-warning' %></td>
                        <td><%= link_to 'Eyða', paper, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                         <% paper_total_cost = paper_total_cost + (paper.paper_cost.to_i) %>
                         <% paper_total_trees = paper_total_trees + (( paper.paper_weight.to_f/1000)*15) %>
                         <% paper_total_staff_ratio = paper_total_staff_ratio + (paper.paper_weight.to_i / current_user.staff) %> 
                    </tr>   
                <% end %>
            </tbody>

    </table>
</div>          

                <div class="row">
                    <div class=" col-md-2 panel panel-default pull-right" >
                        <div class="panel panel-heading ">
                            <h5 class="user-name">User: <% if current_user && current_user %> 
                            <%= current_user.name %>, 
                            Staff: <%= current_user.staff %>
                             <% end %>  
                          </h5>   
                        </div>     
                        <div class="panel-body">         
                            <h6 class="pull-right">Pappír Kostnaður Samtals:<%= number_with_precision(paper_total_cost.to_f, precision: 2) %> kr </h6><br>
                            <h6 class="pull-right">Fjöldi Trjáa vegna Pappírs notkunar:<%= number_with_precision(paper_total_trees.to_f, precision: 2) %> Tré </h6><br>
                             <h6 class="pull-right">Magn Pappírs f. hvert stöðugildi:<%= number_with_precision(paper_total_staff_ratio.to_f, precision: 2) %> Kg </h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>  

                <%= link_to 'New Paper', new_paper_path %>
```

My papers_controller.rb

```
class PapersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_paper, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]


def index
    @papers = Paper.all

end

def create
    @paper = Paper.new(paper_params)

    if @paper.save
        flash[:success] = "Messages sent."
        redirect_to paper_path(@paper)
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Error occured, message has not been sent."
        redirect_to new_paper_path
    end     


end

def new
    @paper = Paper.new
end

def edit
end

def show
end

def update
        if @paper.update(paper_params)
        flash[:success] = "Line was successfully updated"
        redirect_to papers_path(@paper)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end     

end

def destroy
    @paper.destroy
    flash[:danger] = "Line was successfully destroyed"
    redirect_to papers_path
end


private

def set_paper
    @paper = Paper.find(params[:id])
end
def paper_params
    params.require(:paper).permit(:paper_type, :date, :paper_weight, :paper_cost, :env_paper_weight)
end


end
```

my paper.rb Model

```
class Paper < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users 

end
```

Comment: Your example is a bit lengthy and complicated. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, I´ll keep that in mind for my future posts, thanks for the tip @kimmmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the calculations into the model by defining functions in the model.

The first calculation uses current_user, which will not be in the model by default, so that'll have to be a parameter. The other two are just using paper's attributes; pardon my poor naming, I'm not clear what the second two metrics are.

```
class Paper
  has_many :users

  def paper_weight_per_capita(current_user)
    paper_weight.to_i / current_user.staff
  end

  def paper_weight_metric1
    ( env_paper_weight / paper_weight)* 100)
  end

  def paper_weight_metric2
    (( paper_weight.to_f/1000)*15)
  end
end
```

And in your view

```
<%= paper.paper_weight_per_capita(current_user) %>
<%= paper.paper_weight_metric1 %>
```

If you want the running total in your layout then you'll need to load the paper objects on every page. You can do this with an application_controller before_action, though [some folks don't like this approach](http://jgaskins.org/blog/2014/08/25/better-alternative-to-rails-before_action-to-load-objects) and [here](http://craftingruby.com/posts/2015/05/31/dont-use-before-action-to-load-data.html), but I think it is a reasonable way for you now.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :load_running_totals

  def load_running_totals
    # method 1. Similar to how the calculation is done in the view.
    # @paper_weight_per_capita = Papers.all.map(&:paper_weight_per_capita, current_user).reduce(&:+)

    # method 2. does the summation in the database without having to load all the records into ruby. (weight needs to be a number in the db.)
    @paper_weight_per_capita = Papers.sum(:weight) / current_user.staff
  end
end
```

Now in any view (including your layout):

```
<%= @paper_weight_per_capita %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @andynu, this is really helpful, I tried basically the same thing earlier tonight, but it didn´t work, I guess it is because I placed the  <%= paper.paper_weight_per_capita(current_user) %> code outside the <% end %> tag, thats just me being a Newbie :) :)

Comment: I´m not so sure if I understand the before_action bit completely:                 By # exactly replicating your current calculation, do you mean that I should copy/paste the  Methods from the Paper model? or should I Copy/Paste the running total calculation I already have in the view to the "def running_totals"?

Comment: I was offering two ways to do the same thing. The first way `@paper_weight_per_capita = Papers.all.map(&:paper_weight_per_capita, current_user).reduce(&:+)` is similar to how you were doing the calculation in the view. It loads ALL the records then goes through them one by one doing the paper_weigh_per_capita calculation for each and then adds the result together. The second method adds all the weights up in the database and then divides by the staff. This doesn't load all the individual paper records. It should be faster. I recommend the second calculation.